# While loop continuing to run despite condition failing

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sent = "y";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome!\nThis program compares two letters in a sentence.");
    while(!sent.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence or X to exit: ");
        sent = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the first letter: ");
        while(!input.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number not text!");
            input.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the first letter: "); 
        }
        a = input.nextInt(); 


        System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the second letter: ");
        while(!input.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number not text!");
            input.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the second letter: "); 
        }
        b = input.nextInt(); 

       System.out.println();

       char c = sent.charAt(a);
       char d = sent.charAt(b);

       if(c==d) {
           System.out.println(c+" and "+d+" are identical.\n");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println(c+ " and "+ d + " are unique characters. \n");
       }    

    }
    System.out.print("GoodBye!");


}
```

This loop continues to run even if you input X and I don't know why. Also, when you input a text instead of a number, the error message will like so: 
Error! Please enter a number not text!
Enter the numeric location of the first letter: Error! Please enter a number not text!
Enter the numeric location of the first letter:

Only the third sentence will take in user input.

Answer (score 1):

This code `sent = input.next()`
is not reading a whole sentence. It just reads one word.
Try nextLine() instead.

Also, you should test the exit condition immediately after `sent` is set.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sent = "y";
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome!\nThis program compares two letters in a sentence.");
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence or X to exit: ");
    sent = input.next();
    while(!sent.equalsIgnoreCase("X")) {
        //moved accepting input above while condition.This will fix
        //X not recognized issue

        System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the first letter: ");
        while(!input.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number not text!");
            input.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the first letter: "); 
        }
        a = input.nextInt(); 


        System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the second letter: ");
        while(!input.hasNextInt()) { 
            System.out.println("Error! Please enter a number not text!");
            input.nextLine(); 

            System.out.print("Enter the numeric location of the second letter: "); 
        }
        b = input.nextInt(); 

       System.out.println();

       char c = sent.charAt(a);
       char d = sent.charAt(b);

       if(c==d) {
           System.out.println(c+" and "+d+" are identical.\n");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println(c+ " and "+ d + " are unique characters. \n");
       }    

    }
    System.out.print("GoodBye!");


 }
```

Comment: in your version "sent" is only set once.